# I'm trying to make a decimal to binary converter and the result is printing right-to-left and the correct way is left-to-right

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a binary-to-decimal converter on my own. I tried arrays, but with unspecified lengths of binary representations for each number, I found it hard to use them. So now I'm trying with a ternary operator, and it works but the result is showing left-to-right when the correct answer should be right-to-left. Do anyone have a better method or way to make this thing right?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//function that converts decimal to binary
string DecimaltoBinary(int d){

//variable that is going to store the binary representation
string decimal;

    //keep dividing by 2 till variable d reaches 0
    while(d!=0){

        //variabable decimal is going to store the binary representation
        decimal += (d % 2 == 0 ? "0": "1");

        //decimal number divided by 2
        d /= 2;
    }
    //this function is going to return the binary representation
    return decimal;
}

int main(){
    
    int decimal;

    cout<<"Input the decimal number: "<<endl;

    cin>>decimal;

    cout<<DecimaltoBinary(decimal)<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could, say, reverse the string before returning it.

Comment: Or preallocate a string of the required length, and fill in the digits by [iterating it in reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin).

Comment: "How to reverse my string" has been asked many times here, if I'm understanding this question correctly.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you so much. Really simple fix, I didnt think of that.

Comment: I thought we'd already been through the discussion about *not* closing questions like this against that generic, "What is a debugger ...?" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution using your existing code is just to reverse the assignment:

```
decimal = (d % 2 == 0 ? "0": "1") + decimal;
```